# move sound from left to right

Tags: iphone, audio

How to move sound from left to right of earphones in iPhone?

Comment: you want to move all sound to the right side? or switch the left with the right sound?

Comment: I want to move all sound to the right side.

Comment: Search for the Apple 3D sound iPhone example. I think it uses OpenAL - does what you want though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want the pan property of the AVAudioPlayer. Check the [AVAudioPlayer documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)

From the pan property:

> By setting this property you can
>   position a sound in the stereo field.
>   A value of –1.0 is full left, 0.0 is
>   center, and 1.0 is full right.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the sample app on Apple website: [oalTouch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/oalTouch/Introduction/Intro.html)

Answer (score 1):

On IPhone 4 iOS 5.0 if you go to general, then accesablility and scroll down, there is an option to do what you need