# Can I play separate musics/sounds from the left and right?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I want to play separate sounds same time from the left and right in iOS app.
(e.g)
The one is heard from right.
The other is heard from left.

I found OpenAL can set the location of the sound source.
But, OpenAL can't play mp3.

I want to only set "left" or "right" location of the sound source.
I am looking for simple way.

Please tell me a better way and advice.

Comment: Possibly related? http://stackoverflow.com/q/4085906/620197

Comment: Yeah, it's a dupe.

Comment: Thank you. I've solved. Sorry for duplicate question.